# validar el ancho de imagen

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs

alguien me podria ayudar a como validar el el ancho de una imagen a la hora de cargarla, hasta el momento estoy validando el tipo y el peso de la imagen y quiera validar el ancho de la imagen, estoy trabajando con vuejs y laravel, de antemano muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
onFileChange(e) {
            var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
            if (!files.length)
            return;
            if(files[0].type == 'image/jpeg')
            {
                var fileSize = (files[0].size); 
                if(fileSize < (51200)) {
                     this.createImage(files[0]);
                }
                else{
                    alert("La imagen supera el tamaño permitido.");
                }
            }else{
                alert("Solo puede cargar imágenes jpeg.");
            }

        },
        createImage(file) {
            var image = new Image();
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.organizacion[0].l_logo = ((e.target.result).split(","))[1];
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        },
```

Comment: Posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146652/validar-tama%C3%B1oalto-y-ancho-de-imagen-javascript

Answer (score 0):

pudieras validarlo a través del:

```
var image = new image() 
image.onload = (data) => {
 console.log(data.width);
}
```

Recuerda que `image.onload` es llamado luego que la imagen termine de cargar por lo tanto tendrás que prevenir la sin-cronicidad.

te dejo la referencia del evento
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload