# Devolver valor a una variable al salir de una función con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
var arrayArchivos = [];
var bandera = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':file').change(function(){
        filePreview(this);
    });
});

function filePreview(input) 
{
    $.each(input.files, function(index, elem){
        if(elem.type == "image/jpeg" || elem.type == "image/png")
        {
          var img = new Image();
        
          img.onload = function () {
                if(this.width.toFixed(0) >= 600 && this.height.toFixed(0) >= 600)
                {
                    var imagen = $("<div class='content-prev'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove i-img' onClick='eliminarArchivo(this);'></i>"
                               + "<img src='" + e.target.result + "' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div>");
                    $("#previewImagenes").append(imagen);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Tamaño(s) de imagen no admitido(s)', 'Minimo de ancho admitido: 600px<br>Minimo de alto admitido: 600px', 'error');
                    bandera = true;
                }
          }
          
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(elem);
        }
        else
        {
            Swal.fire('Formato incorrecto de imagen', 'Formatos admitidos: jpg y png', 'error');
            bandera = true;
        }

        
    if(bandera == true)
        {
            alert("entro al if");
            return false;
        }
     
      arrayArchivos.push(elem); 
    });
}

function eliminarArchivo(elem)
{
    var index = $(elem).parent().index();
    arrayArchivos.splice(index, 1);
    $(elem).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
.i-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content-prev{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@9.5.3/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@9.5.3/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="file" id="archivos" name="archivos[]" multiple>
<div class="previewImagenes" id="previewImagenes"></div>
</form>
```

Tengo esa función para trabajar la pre visualización de las imágenes y tengo dos problemas que no se como resolverlos, ojala que pudieran orientarme:

El primer problema viene en el momento de comparar el tamaño de la imagen cargada ya que siempre marca que el ancho y alto son 0.

El segundo problema esta en que tengo una variable `bandera` inicializada en **false**, dentro de la función `onload` están las condicionales que permiten determinar si la imagen cargada es del formato pedido y si las medidas están dentro de lo establecido, si cualquiera de las dos condiciones no se cumplen seteo la variable `bandera` a **true** pero el problema es que fuera de la función `onload` la variable `bandera` sigue con el valor de **false**.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Validar tamaño(alto y ancho) de imagen Javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/146652/validar-tama%c3%b1oalto-y-ancho-de-imagen-javascript)

Comment: Funciona para el tamaño pero sigue sin cambiar el valor de la variable bandera fuera de la función onload

Comment: Si ya declaraste `bandera` en contexto global, quita `var` dentro de la función, porque con eso tendrías otra variable local: `bandera = false;`

Comment: Sigue sin cambiar el valor

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código donde defines la variable y donde tratas de acceder. O bien, defínela antes del `onload`.

Comment: Ya lo edite Triby

Comment: Debajo de `var arrayArchivos = [];` coloca `var bandera = false;` y asegúrate de que no exista otro `var bandera = ...`, eliminando solo `var`

Comment: Sigue sin cambiar el valor

Comment: Ya vi el "error": Cuando seleccionas una imagen que no tiene las medidas mínimas no se muestra la alerta, simplemente porque _onload_ se ejecuta hasta que se haya cargado la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

La función *onload* de la imagen es asíncrona, el resto de código continúa ejecutándose y la variable `$bandera` se actualiza hasta que la imagen se cargó.

Una opción es "crear una pausa" para dar tiempo a que se cargue la imagen y poder saber si la variable cambió. En teoría, no es la mejor opción, porque podría haber algún proceso en el navegador que demore la carga de imágenes y, por tanto, el tiempo de pausa no sea suficiente.

```js
var arrayArchivos = [];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(':file').change(function(){
        filePreview(this);
    });
});

function filePreview(input) 
{
    $.each(input.files, function(index, elem){
        var bandera = false;
        if(elem.type == "image/jpeg" || elem.type == "image/png")
        {
          var img = new Image();
        
          img.onload = function (e) {
                if(this.width.toFixed(0) >= 600 && this.height.toFixed(0) >= 600)
                {
                    var imagen = $("<div class='content-prev'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove i-img' onClick='eliminarArchivo(this);'></i>"
                               + "<img src='" + e.target.src + "' style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'></div>");
                    $("#previewImagenes").append(imagen);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Tamaño(s) de imagen no admitido(s)', 'Minimo de ancho admitido: 600px<br>Minimo de alto admitido: 600px', 'error');
                    bandera = true;
                }
          }
          
          img.src = URL.createObjectURL(elem);
        }
        else
        {
            Swal.fire('Formato incorrecto de imagen', 'Formatos admitidos: jpg y png', 'error');
            bandera = true;
        }
        // Esperar para analizar el resultado
        setTimeout(function() {        
          if(bandera == true)
          {
              alert("entro al if");
          }
          arrayArchivos.push(elem);
        }, 300);
    });
}

function eliminarArchivo(elem)
{
    var index = $(elem).parent().index();
    arrayArchivos.splice(index, 1);
    $(elem).parent().remove();
}
```

```css
.i-img{
    position: absolute;
    top: 7;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.content-prev{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@9.5.3/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert2@9.5.3/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="file" id="archivos" name="archivos[]" multiple>
<div class="previewImagenes" id="previewImagenes"></div>
</form>
```